# Where does a Remote SSIS package actually run

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent

We have a legacy Sql Agent job that runs on Server A.  The job Step points to a SSIS package on Server B.  In which environment does that package actually run?  We assume that it executes in the environment of the agent that calls it, but because of some observations that we are seeing (especially related to the file system), we are not sure.

The remote package has two connections -- a file system connection and a database connection.

*The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.*

Comment: How is the package stored? SSISDB catalog on server B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSIS is a client side service/tools , so it will run where the package is physically located.

In your case the SQL Agent Job on `ServerA` is only executing the package, the package that is on `ServerB`, All the data processing and Data flow happens on the `ServerB`.

The package itself may have many connections to flat files or databases but all the data from those flat files and databases will flow to `ServerB` and not to `ServerA`.

I hope this answers your question and has cleared any confusion.

Comment: That seems to be the behavior I observe but can't find documentation to back it up.